# How to draw an arc shape in Sketch?

Tags: shapes, sketch-app

Is there any way to draw an arc shape with rounded ends like this in sketch app?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out this video on how to draw a Pie Graph: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qsjh79E4S-o

Comment: It would be great to include the basic instructions from the video, particularly since the video has been removed.

Comment: Yep, the video is not available